# Django Table already exist

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

Here is my Django Migration file.
When I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations/migrate
```

I get this error.

```
Error:-

    django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'tickets_duration' already exists")
```

I have dropped the database and running it but still get the same error.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Duration',
            fields=[
                ('Id', models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_column=b'duration_id', default=uuid.uuid4, serialize=False, editable=False)),
                ('duration', models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column=b'duration')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ErrorCount',
            fields=[
                ('Id', models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_column=b'error_id', default=uuid.uuid4, serialize=False, editable=False)),
                ('error', models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column=b'error')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='OutageCaused',
            fields=[
                ('Id', models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_column=b'error_id', default=uuid.uuid4, serialize=False, editable=False)),
                ('outage_caused', models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column=b'outage_caused')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Pg',
            fields=[
                ('Id', models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_column=b'pg_id', default=uuid.uuid4, serialize=False, editable=False)),
                ('pg_cd', models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column=b'pg_cd')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='SystemCaused',
            fields=[
                ('Id', models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_column=b'error_id', default=uuid.uuid4, serialize=False, editable=False)),
                ('system_caused', models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column=b'system_caused')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Tickets',
            fields=[
                ('ticket_num', models.CharField(max_length=100, serialize=False, primary_key=True, db_column=b'ticket_id')),
                ('created_dt', models.DateTimeField(db_column=b'created_dt')),
                ('ticket_type', models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column=b'ticket_type')),
                ('addt_notes', models.CharField(max_length=1000, db_column=b'addt_notes')),
                ('row_create_ts', models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 29, 16, 58, 31, 584733))),
                ('row_end_ts', models.DateTimeField(default=b'9999-12-31 00:00:00.00000-00', db_column=b'row_end_ts')),
                ('duration', models.ManyToManyField(to='tickets.Duration')),
                ('error_count', models.ManyToManyField(to='tickets.ErrorCount')),
                ('outage_caused', models.ManyToManyField(to='tickets.OutageCaused')),
```

Comment: Just to make sure: You get this error even if you run `manage.py migrate` on an *empty* database?

Comment: Can you show the output of `python manage.py sqlmigrate <app> <migration>`?

Answer (score 13):

try `python manage.py migrate your_app --fake`. This post talks about it. [Django South - table already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090648/django-south-table-already-exists).

Answer (score 5):

`python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` should work for django 2.2

Answer (score 4):

This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25925368/2142093)

You should run this:

`python manage.py migrate <appname> --fake`

Answer (score 2):

temporary solution may be to comment the creation of existing table(tickets_duration).

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        #migrations.CreateModel(
        #    name='Duration',
        #    fields=[
        #        ('Id', models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_column=b'duration_id', default=uuid.uuid4, serialize=False, editable=False)),
        #        ('duration', models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column=b'duration')),
        #    ],
        #),
        ....
        ....
```

Comment: and where is this class file called MIgration?

Answer (score 1):

**version:-Django 3.X**

***If above solution doesn't work :***

```
python manage.py migrate <appname> --fake
```

If it doesn't work then have a look at the migrations folder you will find that there will be some missing changes which u have done in models.py but somehow Django is unable to capture, so find it there and again do some changes (even a small) to that model fields and then use ,

```
py manage.py makemigrations app_name
py manage.py migrate app_name
or
py manage.py makemigration <appname> --fake
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an inconsistent situation of Database.

You may do the followings:

1. Comment out the code for your last added model.
2. Run makemigrations and then migrate --fake, to get the record sync at present situation.
3. Now, uncomment your last added model, and run makemigrations again;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using sqlite3 because of the way Django creates the third join table. From the docs,

> Behind the scenes, Django creates an intermediary join table to represent the many-to-many relationship. By default, this table name is generated using the name of the many-to-many field and the name of the table for the model that contains it.

So basically, the third table is created by concatenating the two table names. This doesn't work with sqlite3 because [table names in sqlite3 are case insensitive](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-syntax#:%7E:text=SQLite%20is%20a%20case%20insensitive,name%20can%20be%20used%20interchangeably).

The resolution is to add the `db_table` option when declaring your `ManyToManyField`.

```
models.ManyToManyField(to='tickets.Duration', db_table='_Duration')
```